# не работает гравитация

Tags: c#, unity3d

Во всех источниках говориться что как только добавишь Rigidbody то на объект сразу начнёт действовать физика, но  меня объект на падает, причём у меня включённом параметре use gravity
как это исправить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Чтобы что-то упало, оно должно сколько-то весить.

Comment: @aepot, не правда, гравитация больших тел меняет траекторию фатонов которые не имеют массы вообще) Разница масс имеет значение только при столкновении, объект с маленькой массой не сдвинет объект с сильно превосходящей. Так-же и в игровой симуляции) Дело скорее в том что, объект начнет падать не как только добавить компонент, а сцена будет запущена!

Comment: @aepot, это даже написали в [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-mass.html): `A common mistake is to assume that heavy objects fall faster than light ones. This is not true as the speed is dependent on gravity and drag` lol 

Comment: @Yaroslav ускорение свободного падения - константа, это школьная физика. А вот если вес объекта 0 - то он будет невесомый. В реальной физике все имеет вес, а в виртуальной возможно всякое, я сказал именно об этом.

Comment: @aepot, вес? какой? на орбитальной станции твой вес будет 0 , а на земле он плод воображения , а в физике есть только масса . Гравитация это не тяга, гравитация это уровень искажения пространства энергией, который ещё называют колодец (гравитационный) в которого все и падают включая люксоны, подобно фатонам (0 массы) падающим в черную дыру. `E = m*c^2` вот реальная физика ставящая равенство между массой и энергией, не позволяющая называть что-то безмассовое ничем, мол если что-то существует значит у него есть масса, нет это вопрос энергии, в школе об этом тоже упоминают .

Comment: @aepot, совсем забыл, уже давным давно специально продеманстрировали всему миру наглядно) [Google: молоток и перо на луне](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA+%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B5&source=lmns&bih=666&biw=360&client=ms-android-transsion&prmd=niv&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvnLeZ8Y36AhWKk4sKHblXA4YQ_AUoAHoECAAQAw#sbfbu=1&pi=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B5). Луна кстате падает на землю с той же скоростью что и все)

Comment: Да, объект имеет вес. Но не падает и всегда летает на 1 высоте.

Comment: @Yaroslav _в физике есть только масса_  xD `P = m*g`

Comment: ответить нет а посраться в комментариях пожалуйста

Comment: Спец по Unity как раз @Yaroslav, а я просто физику в школе хорошо учил (наверное), я больше по C# и .NET без Unity соображаю. И если он не ответил, значит вы как-то не так задали вопрос, либо привели недостаточно данных для определения источника проблемы, вследствие чего непосредственно ответить на данный вопрос не представляется возможным.

Comment: ну я описал всё что знаю о проблеме, я в юнити не сильно шарю и поэтому не знаю в чём может быть проблема, при запуске проекта объект просто висит в воздухе, а копировал 1 в 1 из разных гайдов и ничего не менялось, вот и думаю что это вопрос в настройка проекта, которые  авторы гайдов умалчивают, считая что все о них знают. вот и надеюсь что мне скажут где их надо настроить ну или хотя бы де это поискать